# Setting default_scope according to some criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default-scope

I'm trying to set default scope according to some criteria determined by ana ActionController before_filter. In controller:

```
  before_filter :authorize
  ...
  def authorize
    if some_condition
      @default_scope_conditions = something
    elsif another_condition
      @default_scope_conditions = something_else
    end
  end
```

Inside the ActiveRecord

```
default_scope :conditions => @default_scope_conditions
```

But it doesn't seem to work, the before filter gets called but the default_scope doesn't get set. Could you please advise me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it or suggest me some other way of achieving that.

Comment: You set @default_scope_conditions - which is an instance variable from the **controller** and you expect to read it from the **model**. It is not visible from the model unless passed as method parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set **@default_scope_conditions** - which is an instance variable from the **controller** and you expect to read it from the **model**. It is not visible from the model unless passed as method parameter.

More, this approach would break the MVC principle that separates the model logic from the controller logic: Your model shouldn't automatically  access info about current state of the controller.

What you can do: use anonymous scopes.

```
  def scope_user
    if some_condition
      @default_scope_conditions = something
    elsif another_condition
      @default_scope_conditions = something_else
    end

    @user_scoped = User.scoped(:conditions => @default_scope_conditions)
  end
```

Then, in your method, you can:

```
def my_method
  users = @user_scoped.all
end
```

or

```
def my_method
  User.with_scope(:conditions => @default_scope_conditions) do
    # .. 
    @users = User.all #users get scoped
    @products.users # also gets scoped
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try one default_scope and override it using custome finder.

The default options can always be overridden using a custom finder.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => '`users`.name asc'
end
```

User.all # will use default scope
User.all(:order => 'name desc') # will use passed in order option.

Then you can try something like following

```
before_filter :authorize
  ...
  def authorize
    if some_condition
      @order = ''  # default scope
    elsif another_condition
      @order = something_else
    end
  end

  def method_name
    User.all(:order => @order)
  end
```

No Check though.