# default_scope for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to implement `gem devise` to my app.
Before that my top model was `Album` but now it `belongs_to :user` (from devise).

Then I added to the albums_controller.rb:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

It works great - user has to log in from now on. And now I wish him to do everything with albums in his scope. I found that insted of that method:

```
def index
  @albums = Album.all
end
```

I could use:

```
@albums = current_user.albums
```

and so on for every method I have. I was wondering if there's a better way - to set `current_user` as default scope for every action/method in the albums controller. Then I found something interesting [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class). I could add it to Album's model but I'm not sure how best costruct `where` clause for the `current_user`. Maybe something like this:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

I'm not even sure if it's right direction. I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: I would advise against this. It sounds like a terrible idea. Your models concern is data, not authorisation. There are many ways to handle this. See the pundit gem.

Comment: I'm actually a bit disappointed as I can't find examples on devise's page. I think it's a really common user case.

Comment: You can't find examples because no one does this. There is absolutely  not a single good reason that should compel you to do this. This is what controllers are for.

Comment: No no... you got me wrong. I'm looking for an example how to limit controllers actions to one users data. The way I proposed is the only one I came into and I never said it's correct.

Comment: `gem pundit` doesn't change anything here - it's another way to manage roles and so on. Looking [here](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes) I still have to modify every action in my controller to add `where` clause.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657924/setting-default-scope-according-to-some-criteria#answer-2658028) looks promising as well.

Comment: and [this](http://vitobotta.com/rails-multi-tenancy-devise-default-scope/) is exactly how I proposed. Now I'm even more confused..

Comment: I would use this method for multitenancy, but not for a user. What the difference? An organisation can have many users, and you may want to enable access on a per organisation level. Limiting access on a per user level is not a good idea. What if you need to give someone admin access to allow them to change any album? You are stuck calling `unscoped`. Unless you know what you are doing, stay away from default_scope. I was just bitten by this last week and spent a good amount of time fixing it. The closest I go to use it is for ordering records: `default_scope { order(name: :desc) }`

Comment: I appreciate your advice and I'll take the lesson. Lets leave model as it is than and the pundit as well. What's the best way to do this than ?

Comment: See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this at all. The best approach is to use the controller to scope your models. This type of thing doesn't belong to the model.

```
def index
  @albums = current_user.albums
end
```

If you want to avoid the repetition, create methods to retrieve the object. So instead of this:

```
def show
  @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
end
def edit
  @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
end
# etc...
```

You can do this:

```
def index
  albums
end
def show
  album
end
def update
  if album.update(album_params)
end
# etc...

private
def albums
  @albums ||= current_user.albums
end
def album
  @album ||= current_user.albums.find(params[:id)
end
```

You can even avoid calling the album method from the action by using a `before_filter`, but this is not a good way. You always tend to forget to add and remove actions from the filter.

```
before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def set_album
  @album ||= current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then your instance variables are created in one place. As @wacaw suggested, if this appeals to you, you can take it further and use the [decent_exposure](https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure) gem. Personally, I am happy to stop at the controller and use instance methods in my views.

If you have more complex authorisation needs I suggest you use [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), although the latter does not appear to be actively maintained.

There is more on [decent_exposure](http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure?view=comments#comment_151102) on Rails Casts. If you really fancy this type of scoping, look at this [Rails Cast on Multitenancy with Scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes). But that is meant for organisations that have many of users, not a single user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so detailed answer. I'm on [Rails Cast on Multitenancy with Postgresql](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql) right now. And the point to have more users and isolate their data is exactly the point here. I already implemented something based on tirdadc's idea. And I'm wondering about switching to wacaw's advice of decent_exposure as I have to clean my controlers a bit as well. A lot of things to do at once so it'll take me a bit to find where it'll let me finally.

Comment: i can see why one might need it. for example if you want to filter your autocomplete result by user.id

Comment: @KonstantinVoronov pass the user or user id as a parameter to the method. You really don't want to be doing this type of thing in the model.

Answer (score 5):

You should just use a regular named scope instead:

`scope :for_user, lambda{ |user| where(:user_id => user.id) }`

and then in your controller replace

`@albums = Album.all` with `@albums = Album.for_user(current_user)`

While you can theoretically pass [arguments](http://mpov.timmorgan.org/use-a-proc-with-activerecords-defaultscope-me/) to your default scope, the above is the preferred approach.

Comment: I'm using latest versions of Ruby/Rails. I'm not on any approach yet, as I have no idea how it should be done properly. This is exactly the question here.

Comment: @Mohamad: the default scope part or the regular named scope? The latter should be fine.

Comment: @tirdadc the `default_scope`, which is an awful idea!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea either to be honest, and strikes me as a misuse of `default_scope`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @tirdadc which then becomes no different than calling `current_user.albums`.

Comment: not the same as I can use it in `before_action` and makes it depended on the users role (user or admin) in the future just in one place.

Comment: I did as you suggest and it worked pretty well. Anyway as for now looks I don't need that approach as I moved to `gem apartment` where I create separate schemas for each user. I would probably try to move to wacaw's idea if I have to use it but I think that Mohamed's answer is most complete.

Answer (score 1):

Use helper for creating declarative interfaces in controllers

https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

example for devise:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure?view=comments#comment_151102

Comment: I'll consider that - it would push me to change more than less (as I would have to change all controllers methods, views and tests) but it's still interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-defaults) gem to keep your controllers clean of boilerplate code. The following code is everything you need to build a standard CRUD-Controller that automatically scopes to the `current_user` and checks authentication.

```
class AlbumsController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def begin_of_association_chain
    current_user
  end
end
```